# Adjust height of dropdown menu option in Dash-Plotly?

Tags: plotly-dash

I have a dash dropdown (dcc.Dropdown) created using the code;

```
                    style={"display": "flex", "align-items": "center"},
                    children=[
                        dcc.Dropdown(
                            options=[<list of options that are bit longer sentences>],
                            value="How good are teaching staff at explaining things?",
                            id="questions_dropdown",
                            style={"width": "100%", "max-width": "300px", "display": "block"}
                        )
                    ]
                )
```

How do I fix the overlapping problem?
Showing the option in two lines are fine (If possible showing in the same line is also fine as long as it is just the area of options that extend in width).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used *optionHeight* as in the code below;

```
dcc.Dropdown(
    ['New York City', 'Montreal', 'Paris', 'London', 'Amsterdam', 'Berlin', 'Rome'],
    'Paris', id='option-height-example-dropdown', optionHeight=50
)
```

Not Ideal, because some options need small space but others need more space. But this is what I have now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add this property to your style:

```
overflow-wrap: break-word;
```

Comment: Thank you but no improvement.